# Page.IsPostBack is always returning false in Sharepoint Sandboxed Solutions

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution

I've a webpart with a single asp:button, I've noticed that the `Page.IsPostBack` is not changing its state even though the user click on the button.

Also,I got an error when trying to using something like this `Page.Request.Url`

> Message   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Have someone went through an issue like this?

The Client is a Sharepoint Online.

Local Environment: Sharepoint 2013 On Premise, Visual Web Part for Sandboxed solution

Comment: Does the page refresh when the user clicks on the button?

Comment: Yes, it does refresh and the ispostBack is false.

Comment: What logic is written in the button? Does it do basic stuff or does it redirect you to this page? If it's a redirect, then postback will be false.

Comment: I have a webpart with a asp:button with an action and in this action there is no logic yet, I've just tested the 
if (Page.IsPostBack) and noticed that this is always returning false.. and it does not make any sense for me.

Comment: Yea, that's weird. Have you tried the same web part as farm solution? Have you tried another web part in sandboxed solution?

Comment: In a farm solution this is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Make Sure that *'EnbleViewState'* property of your page or button is
  set to *True*.
- Set button property `UseSubmitBehavior="False`"

Comment: I've tried this and unfortunately this change does not solved this weird issue. 
I was looking and I've found this link: https://support.cloudshare.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200332875-An-unknown-exception-occurred-while-executing-a-sandboxed-code  but I do not know if this will resolve my problem.

Comment: You've got SP on the same machine as AD as stated in the article?

Comment: I have an AD on VM but it is not the same AD as my company uses. Do you think this may be a problem? I have other vm using the AD of my company and in this VM is working fine, but the problem is that we have the whole environment set on this one and the VM is very slow...

Comment: When you retrieve data from a Null object you will get this error : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". So,check for Null before retrieving.